# How do you load and start a launchd job without using a plist file?

Tags: launchd

The manual page for `launchctl` mentions that the `load` and `unload` subcommands are legacy subcommands, which implies that they're no longer needed for loading and starting a launchd job.

However, I'm not aware of any way to actually define a launchd job and its properties and then load it for the first time without using a plist file and passing it in to the `load` subcommand.

Does `launchctl` offer a way of defining and loading a job using its other subcommands? If so, how does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does offer such a way - and actually it's stated in the manual just below where it says that the others are legacy.

So to quote the man page for `launchctl` in the section for legacy subcommands - for the subcommands `load` and `unload` it says:

> Recommended alternative subcommands: bootstrap | bootout | enable |
> disable

So those are the newer subcommands, you want to look at.

Here's a few examples:

Before if you used `load` like this:

```
launchctl load my.plist
```

You'll now write one of these:

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap system my.plist
launchctl bootstrap user/$(id -u) my.plist
launchctl bootstrap gui/$(id -u) my.plist
```

The difference being that you now have to specify the domain target. The difference here is that `system` means that it going to be a system daemon that runs as the super user, compared to `user` meaning that it will run as the given user, and `gui` meaning that it will run as the given user, but only be active when the user is logged in to the graphical user interface. There's also a `session` and `pid` target domain if you have more advanced needs.

The `$(id -u)` is basically just a short hand for finding your own user's id. You can run `id -u` in the Terminal to get it if you do not know it, and then you can just specificy it manually like for example so:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/501 my.plist
```

The replacement for `unload` is quite similar:

```
sudo launchctl bootout system my.plist
launchctl bootout user/$(id -u) my.plist
launchctl bootout gui/$(id -u) my.plist
```

So the above covers how to move away from the legacy subcommands to the recommended subcommands instead.

The second part of your question is whether you can do this without using a plist file. The answer is no. The `bootstrap` subcommand requires you to specify a service-path, which can be either a plist, a XPC service bundle - or a directory of either of those. XPC service bundle are used by application developers, but they also include a plist file - so going that route is not going to save you from having a plist file.

You can of course do various sorts of work-arounds with scripts or utility programs so that you do not need to manually create and maintain plist files. You could even use for example a named pipe to avoid having to actually store the contents of the plist file on disk, but I cannot see the practical benefit of that.

Comment: Okay, that clears some things up, though it answers half of my question. The other half is: is there a way to start / bootstrap a launchd job without using a plist file?

Comment: Ah - I never actually say the other part of your question. It is really only in the title of the question - I read the question itself and thought that you only knew how to use load with a plist, and now wanted to use a non-legacy command with a plist.

Comment: I have answered the second part of your question now. By the way, could you expand on _why_ you do not want to use a plist file? - Is there something else you would like to use instead? - or what were you thinking of?

Comment: I have an app that needs to make a temporary launchd job that runs once and then removes itself. Currently I'm doing this using a plist saved to a temporary location, but it's more complicated and error prone trying to fully clean everything up afterwards when a temporary file is involved. If it were possible to start the job with just an invocation to `launchctl` then that would simply things. But the temporary file works well enough.

Comment: Perhaps using launchctl is not the right choice. Why do you need to run a launchd job only once? What does the job do? Perhaps that can be solved in an easier manner

Comment: It's an offshoot of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922892/how-to-prevent-the-xyz-would-like-to-access-files-in-your-downloads-folder-mes but the short answer is that it's working around erroneous, confusing and annoying nags generated by recent versions of macOS. It's definitely not a normal use case for launchctl.